# How can I make fat-free whipped "cream" with a whipped cream dispenser?

Tags: whipped-cream, whipping-siphon

Does anyone have ideas to make fat-free or low-fat whipped "cream" in a whipped cream dispenser (I have an iSi one)?

Comment: What is an ISI?

Comment: It is a brand of whipper.

Comment: Should the manufacturer's instructions not tell you this, then?

Comment: What're you trying to do with it? You [can't in general make whipped cream even with half-and-half](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/28222/can-you-make-whipped-cream-with-half-and-half), so while there might be some wacky ways you can make some kind of low-fat milk foam, it's not going to taste or feel like whipped cream.

Comment: add gelatin and keep it cold

Answer (score 5):

There are any number of combinations of hydrocolloid agents that can be used to simulate the viscosity and other properties of dairy cream without the fat or even the dairy. "Modernist Cuisine" by Myhrvold includes a recipe for low fat "cream" which combines skim milk with l-carrageenan, cellulose gum, and whey powder; as well as a recipe for non-dairy whipping cream made from water, cellulose gum, proplene glycol alginate, agar, vegetable oil, and glycerin flake.  [Other recipes](http://www.modernistcookingmadeeasy.com/info/how-to/more/how-to-make-whipped-cream-with-a-whipping-siphon) are less complicated with only a single agent such as agar or [xanthan gum](http://www.molecule-r.com/en/content/70-low-fat-whip-cream)

Comment: Hah, was just watching Nathan's lecture looking for this.  Nice.

Comment: You can also buy fat free "half and half" that's made with those kinds of ingredients (I remember it at least has carageenan anyway) - I'm sure someone out there is making "cream" too, though as long as they're thickening artificially, the "half and half" may be thick enough already.

Comment: Thank you so much Didgeridrew - I can't wait to try the Low Fat Whip Cream with xanthan for my Easter dessert!

Comment: @Jefromi i've tried the half and half with those ingredients and they aren't present in high enough concentrations to make a difference for whipping. They are primarily added to make up for the mouthfeel of the product since there is less fat.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can make something that will look and taste like whipped cream but it wont be whipped cream.

It's the same question as how does one make alcohol free vodka. You can. You can make a really nice drink which will produce a better alcohol like high if you mix water and good ghb but it wont be vodka.

Comment: You'll note that the original questioner quoted "cream"; if it isn't real whipped cream, but is indistinguishable from real whipped cream, then presumably that would be good enough.

Comment: It's not indistinguishable. It's similar and you may even like it more. But you can tell them apart. Like Nutella made in different countries.

Comment: Sounds like that's good enough for the original questioner, which means saying "you can't" isn't a useful answer.